# ¿Cómo crear una conexión VPN entre Linux e Instancia EC2 de Amazon AWS?

Tags: linux, vpn

¿Podrían explicarme cómo usar los recursos de la **VPC** de **Amazon** para crear una **VPN** a la cual me pueda conectar y crear un túnel privado entre mi IP pública y la red VPC de Amazon?

Comment: Podrías probar con la documentación oficial (El tutorial es muy extenso para incluirlo aquí o tratar de traducirlo) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html

Comment: El tutorial que tiene `Amazon` sobre `VPC` es bastante completo y otra opción que podría servirte y que me funcionó bien (cuando no conocía mucho de `amazon`) es [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net "OpenVPN"). Saludos.